# Windows cmd: Differentiate "input command" with "result"

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

is there anyway for us to differntiate "input command" with "result"? As image below, I want to see these phase in other color (red maybe):
`The operation completed successfully.`
`IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.133.251.34`
`IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1`
`ProxyServer    REG_SZ    10.133.94.63:8080`

[image]

Comment: Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question ?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to answer, You need to use **`ANSI Escape Sequences`**, and you are good to go.

#### **`Windows before 10` - no native support for ANSI colors on the console**

For Windows version below 10(8,7,XP and so on), the Windows command console doesn't support output coloring by default.

So, You could install either [Cmder](http://cmder.net/), [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases) or [Mintty](https://mintty.github.io/) (used by default in GitBash and Cygwin) to add coloring support to your Windows command console.

#### **`Windows 10`**

The better part comes here as Windows 10 console support ANSI Escape Sequences and some colors by default.

`NOTE` : The feature is shipped with the Threshold 2 Update in Nov 2015.

**[See the MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx)**

#### ANSI Escape Sequence Codes

See this image below as a reference to color escape sequences available.

[image: ANSI Escape Sequences for colors]

See the last `Combinations` part in the image for examples on `RED` color.

#### See the Batch Script [on Github](https://gist.github.com/mlocati/fdabcaeb8071d5c75a2d51712db24011#file-win10colors-cmd) written by `Michele Locati`

```
@echo off
cls
echo [101;93m STYLES [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[0m [0mReset[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[1m [1mBold[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[4m [4mUnderline[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m [7mInverse[0m
echo.
echo [101;93m NORMAL FOREGROUND COLORS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[30m [30mBlack[0m (black)
echo ^<ESC^>[31m [31mRed[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[32m [32mGreen[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[33m [33mYellow[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[34m [34mBlue[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[35m [35mMagenta[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[36m [36mCyan[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[37m [37mWhite[0m
echo.
echo [101;93m NORMAL BACKGROUND COLORS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[40m [40mBlack[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[41m [41mRed[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[42m [42mGreen[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[43m [43mYellow[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[44m [44mBlue[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[45m [45mMagenta[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[46m [46mCyan[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[47m [47mWhite[0m (white)
echo.
echo [101;93m STRONG FOREGROUND COLORS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[90m [90mWhite[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[91m [91mRed[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[92m [92mGreen[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[93m [93mYellow[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[94m [94mBlue[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[95m [95mMagenta[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[96m [96mCyan[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[97m [97mWhite[0m
echo.
echo [101;93m STRONG BACKGROUND COLORS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[100m [100mBlack[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[101m [101mRed[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[102m [102mGreen[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[103m [103mYellow[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[104m [104mBlue[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[105m [105mMagenta[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[106m [106mCyan[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[107m [107mWhite[0m
echo.
echo [101;93m COMBINATIONS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[31m                     [31mred foreground color[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m                      [7minverse foreground ^<-^> background[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7;31m                   [7;31minverse red foreground color[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m and nested ^<ESC^>[31m [7mbefore [31mnested[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[31m and nested ^<ESC^>[7m [31mbefore [7mnested[0m
```